# $(window).bind('hashchange', function () -- advice needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

does this look like the best way to get the #value out of the url on change, it does work but just wondering if there was a better way.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var map = {
            one: 1,
            two: 2,
            three: 3,
            four: 4
        };
        var hashValue = map[hash.substring(1)];
        alert(hashValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: This question might be more suitable on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: and it won't work in older IE if you care to cater to these + newer browsers can use pushState which is nicer to look at

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.history plugin: http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

It can help you to avoid some crossbrowser problems of hashchange event.

```
function loadContent(hash) {
    alert(hashValue);
    // you can do some ajax here  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.history.init(loadContent);
});
```